# The LoginModel RememberMe is being marked as required field

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using the LoginModel inside asp.net mvc web application which looks as follow:-

```
public class LoginModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
    [Display(Name = "User name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

     [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Remember me?")]
    public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
}
```

but the generated mark-up is as follow:-

```
<div class="input-prepend">
    Remember Me ?  &nbsp;&nbsp;<input data-val="true" data-val-required="The Remember me? field is required." id="RememberMe" name="RememberMe" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="RememberMe" type="hidden" value="false" />
</div>
```

So why the RememberMe is being marked as Required fields , although inside the model class there is no [Required] data annotation specified?

Answer (score 3):

Change the property to use a [nullable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx) bool:

```
[Display(Name = "Remember me?")]
public bool? RememberMe { get; set; }
```

That way you declare that no value given to this property is OK, which means it can be optional. By using a normal `bool`, MVC renders a required error since that property must be either true or false.

EDIT:

Based on your comments, it seems that RememberMe should not be optional, since a NULL value is not satisfactory. In that regard, having RememberMe as `bool` is the way to go. Yes you will get the `data-val-required` stuff in the HTML, but it sounds like that's fine.

EDIT:
OK I see where you're coming from. You really don't want a red asterix next to the `Remember Me` checkbox then you must define `RememberMe` property as `bool?`

Then, when the user submits their data, if `RememberMe.Value is null`, can you manually set `RememberMe.Value` to `false`? Because if the user has not ticked the box, that means they do not want the site to remember them. If you can set the value to false yourself, so that you're not passing NULL to SetAuthCookie, then you'll be fine.

Comment: thanks for the reply , but setting it as an optional bool , will raise an error when calling the following FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie , as it expect a value of type bool..

Comment: Use `RememberMe.Value` when calling SetAuthCookie. The `Value` property will be of type `bool`.

Comment: this will raise the following exception when i tried to login " System.InvalidOperationException: Nullable object must have a value."

Comment: Your problem is that you want `RememberMe` to be optional, which means `RememberMe.Value` could be NULL i.e. `RememberMe.HasValue is false`. In that case you must decide whether to set RememberMe.Value to a default value yourself, if the user hasn't selected true/false.

Comment: ok i got your point, Now i have bool? but the rendered html is still having data-val="true" data-val-required=

Comment: the problem is that i have wrote a javaScript to display a "red *" beside all the fields that have "data-val="true" data-val-required="so now i am getting a red * beside the remember me check box, although users can lo-gin without specifying its value !!!

Comment: i have defiend it as bool? , but this will not remove the Required from the generated html ....